# How do you get rid of the limit of partitions on the C drive?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, windows-8-preview, multi-boot

I am trying to dual run Windows 8 and7.  I read somewhere that to do this you need to make a separate partition on the C drive. When I do this I get this error message

> You cannot create a new volume in this unallocated space because the disk already contains >the maximum number of partitions."

I would like it if someone either told me how to get rid of the limit or let me know if i can run Windows 8 on a partition of my D drive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is your drive? And how many partitions do you already have on it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate partition for installing Windows 8.
You could install Windows 8 to VHD.

VHD is Virtual Hard Disk - just a simple file on any partition.

You need at least 16 GB for 32 bit Windows 8 install (and 20 GB for 64 bit)

[How to install Windows 8 to VHD](http://www.boyans.net/HowTo_InstallWindows8_to_VHD.html)

The benefit of VHD method is that for just a small overhead for disk access you have a complete native installation and don't need a separate partition.

Comment: If I install windows 8 to VHD will I be able to switch from windows 7 to windows 8?

Comment: This was how I did it when I was running 7 and 8.  Now I'm just running 8.  Here's the guide I used when I did it, though: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GuideToInstallingAndBootingWindows8DeveloperPreviewOffAVHDVirtualHardDisk.aspx  It dual boots just as if you had set up dual boot on separate partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert the disk to dynamic before creating the extra partition. To do this within Disk Management:

- Right click on Disk 0 (Grey area that shows the total size of your HD)
- Select 'Convert to Dynamic Disk'
  After you've converted it to a dynamic disk you'll then be able to go and create the new simple partition.

Comment: 331.13 GB on my C and 344.95 on my D I have 3 partitions on my C (which is the one i want to use) but they are given to SYSTEM and recovery and just the other one is boot crash dump etc